# Recommended way of figuring out working environment in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, environment

I'm working on some projects which have some inconsistencies in the source code, and I'm struggling to understand which method is preferred when trying to get working environment name in AWS Lambda functions.

One example is using Lambda's `context` object. Lambda functions can have "aliases" which can be a pointer to specific version, and in our case, aliases are usually "production", "staging", "development" and similar. If `context` is used to get environment name, it is usually done like this:

```js
// NodeJS example
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let environment = "development"
  if ((context && context.invokedFunctionArn.endsWith(':production')) environment = "production";
  if ((context && context.invokedFunctionArn.endsWith(':staging')) environment = "staging";
};
```

Other way is, of course, setting the environmental variable (e.g. `NODE_ENV`). This would probably still require aliasing Lambda functions but alias wouldn't be relevant in code itself:

```js
// NodeJS example
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
};
```

What are benefits of using one or the other approach and is there a recommended way of resolving the environment name in AWS Lambda?